# How can i access to a file on the desktop of my corrupted virtual machine?

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, virtualbox, ubuntu-16.04

I can't set up another virtual box session because when i run the session the computer freeze. I'm using ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0):

You can mount the disk on your Ubuntu Host system

```
VBoxManage clonehd --format RAW windows.vdi windows.img
```

Then

```
mount -t ntfs -o loop,ro ./windows.img /mnt/windows
```

You need to know the file system format you used when installing the VM. Since you are using Windows inside your VM, the file system is most likely `ntfs`.

[Source](https://askubuntu.com/a/19431)

Comment: The first part worked correctly, but when i launch the second command i continue to receive this error:

NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/loop0': Argomento non valido
The device '/dev/loop0' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?